# How do I get player ranking from GameCenter

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am trying to get the global ranking of the player in game center right after I submit a high score to the scoreboard.  However I can not find any documentation on doing this, also I worry that a "score parameter" will not be accurate immediatly.

How does one get a players ranking in Gamecenter.

Here is my score submission code so far

```
if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated
{
    let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "MY APP")
    scoreReporter.value = Int64(score)
    let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
    GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Good 2")

        }
        else
        {
            print("Good 1")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GKScore have a property named rank. It reports the rank of player as
>   per leaderboards specifications.

```
let leaderBoard : GKLeaderboard = GKLeaderboard()

leaderBoard.timeScope = .AllTime
leaderBoard.range = NSMakeRange(1, 1)
leaderBoard.identifier = "Your Leaderboard ID"
leaderBoard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler { (score : [GKScore]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if(error != nil){
        // Handle Error
    }else{

        if(score?.count > 0){

            let score : GKScore = leaderBoard.localPlayerScore!

            let rank : NSInteger = score.rank

            print("rank \(rank)")

        }

    }

}
```